# Generate correct json with p-dropdown PrimeNG

Tags: java, json, typescript, primeng

I am new to Angular and I have the following situation using the API in java:

I have the `class Release` where the category is NOT required (class Category).

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "release")
public class Release {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "id_category")
    private Category;

    (...)
}
```

When I am registering a release on the page created in Angular using the REST API, I am sending the `json` to this API as follows:

```
{"description": "test", "category": {}}
```

due to not having informed the category. But my API returns the following error (in java):

> TransientObjectException - object references an unsaved transient
>   instance - save the transient instance before flushing

I did a test in Postman and sent `json` as follows to register the release:

```
{"description": "test"}
```

This way I can register, then there is the doubt:

The error is in the Angular that is using the `p-dropdown` component of `PrimeNG` as follows:

```
    <p-dropdown placeholder = "Select ..." [autoWidth] = "false"
      [filter] = "true" [options] = "categories"
      [(ngModel)] = "release.category.id" name = "category"
      #category = "ngModel"> </ p-dropdown>
```

or the error is in the category declaration in the class release?

When you register the release informing the category, there are no errors and `json` is sent as follows:

```
{"description": "test", "category": {"id": 1}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the case p-dropdown options accepts Array and here you are returning object

```
{"description": "test", "category": {}}
```

It should be

```
{"description": "test", "category": [{"name":"John", "id": "1"},{"name":"Kan", "id": "2"}]}
```

Than it will accept the array as option.

and you have to use `optionLabel` property to define what key you want as to display in list.

```
<p-dropdown placeholder = "Select ..." [autoWidth] = "false"
  [filter] = "true" [options] = "categories"
  [(ngModel)] = "release.category.id" name = "category"
  #category = "ngModel" [optionLabel]="name"> </ p-dropdown>
```

in that case your ngModel will have whole object if user selects

```
{"name":"John", "id": "1"}
```

If you want it return a single value '1' if user selects John.
than you have to modify option Array like below:

```
[{"label":"John", "value": "1"},{"label":"Kan", "value": "2"}
```

Hope it helps!